# Ignore submit of a certain form in beforeunload

Tags: javascript, jsf, submit, onbeforeunload

I have a Facelet page which contains a form which should display a `beforeunload` message when it contains unsaved data. For that, I am using the following JavaScript:

```
$(window).on('beforeunload', function(){
    var val = document.getElementById("saveFormId:newInputId").value;
    var flagVal = (val=='true');
    if(flagVal)
        return 'Are you sure you want to leave?';
});
```

In the same page, I have another form which changes the locale:

```
<h:form id="localeForm">
    <p:selectOneButton value="#{localeBean.selectedLocale}"
        valueChangeListener="#{localeBean.countryLocaleCodeChanged}"
        onchange="submit()" style="height:1px;margin-top:7px;"
        styleClass="ui-language-button">
        <f:selectItems value="#{localeBean.languages}" />
    </p:selectOneButton>
</h:form>
```

However, this also triggers the `beforeunload` handler. I would like to ignore the submit of the above form in `beforeunload` handler. How can I achieve this?

Comment: I tried the answer but the page would not refresh with the changed locale. the 'onchange=submit' is neccessary for refreshing the whole view

Comment: Kindly reply to the question? I have not received the right answer.

Answer (score 0):

`onchange="submit()"` is going to submit the entire page, triggering the `onbeforeunload` event. You should use ajax to carry out the action:

```
<p:selectOneButton value="#{localeBean.selectedLocale}" style="height:1px;margin-top:7px;"        styleClass="ui-language-button">
    <f:selectItems value="#{localeBean.languages}" />
    <p:ajax event="change" listener="#{localeBean.countryLocaleCodeChanged}" />  
</p:selectOneButton>
```

Depending on your current implementation, you may need to change your `countryLocaleCodeChanged` to accept either 0 arguments or an instance of `AjaxBehaviorEvent`

Comment: I tried this but the page would not refresh with the changed locale. the 'onchange=submit' is neccessary for refreshing the whole view